# Python on Windows: IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, ioerror

I'm trying to remove all files from a folder which contan certain "blacklisted" content. I have this code:

```
import os

black_list = [line for line in open("C:/path/to/blacklist.txt")]

for filename in os.listdir("C:/path/to/files/"):
    content = open(filename).read()
    if any(line in content for line in black_list):
        os.remove(filename)
```

But I get an error like:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'first_file_from_the_folder'
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: This problem is solved by **looking at the results** from `os.listdir` (the first value, which is already problematic, is reflected in the error message), and then consulting the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`os.listdir` returns filenames, not complete path.

```
PATH = "C:/path/to/files/"
for filename in os.listdir(PATH):
    content = open(os.path.join(PATH, filename)).read()
```

Here, `os.path.join` is used for merge the path and the filename.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove the file, it should pass the whole path of file.

```
import os

black_list = [line for line in open("C:/path/to/blacklist.txt")]
path = "C:/path/to/files/"
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    content = open(path+ filename).read()
    if any(line in content for line in black_list):
        os.remove(path + filename)
```