# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory (when it really exist) Python

Tags: python, file-transfer, uart, errno

I'm working on transfer folder of files via uart in python. Below you see simple function, but there is a problem because I get error like in title : `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1.jpg'` where 1.jpg is one of the files in test folder. So it is quite strange because program know file name which for it doesn't exist ?! What I'm doing wrong ?

```
def send2():
    path = '/home/pi/Downloads/test/'
    arr = os.listdir(path)
    for x in arr:
        with open(x, 'rb') as fh:
            while True:
                # send in 1024byte parts
                chunk = fh.read(1024)
                if not chunk: break
                ser.write(chunk)
```

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765227/ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-trying-to-open-a-file, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36477665/python-on-windows-ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Perhaps use  `glob.glob('/home/pi/Downloads/test/*')` instead...

Answer (score 11):

You need to provide the actual full path of the files you want to open if they are not in your working directory :

```
import os
def send2():
    path = '/home/pi/Downloads/test/'
    arr = os.listdir(path)
    for x in arr:
        xpath = os.path.join(path,x)
        with open(xpath, 'rb') as fh:
            while True:
                # send in 1024byte parts
                chunk = fh.read(1024)
                if not chunk: break
                ser.write(chunk)
```

Answer (score 2):

`os.listdir()` just returns bare filenames, not fully qualified paths. These files (probably?) aren't in your current working directory, so the error message is correct -- the files don't exist in the place you're looking for them.

Simple fix:

```
for x in arr:
    with open(os.path.join(path, x), 'rb') as fh:
        …
```

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, code raise Error because file which you are opening is not present at current location from where python code is running.

`os.listdir(path)` returns list of names of files and folders from given location, not full path.

use `os.path.join()` to create full path in `for` loop.
e.g.

```
file_path = os.path.join(path, x)
with open(file_path, 'rb') as fh:
       .....
```

Documentation:

1. [os.listdir(..)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir)
2. [os.path.join(..)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)